# Microsoft adaptive card choiceset iteration

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, adaptive-cards

i have a adaptive card choice set like below, as you can see am trying to get the value under title from a variable which is an array, is there a way i can iterate the choice set automatically because i don't know how many values the array has i want to show all the values inside the array in the choice set title

{
"type" : "Input.ChoiceSet",
"isMultiSelect": true,
"id": "myColor",
"style": "compact",
"value": "1",
"choices": [
{
"title": vars.responsedata.items[0].topic,
"value": "1"
},
{
"title": vars.responsedata.items[1].topic,
"value": "2"
},
{
"title": "Recording 3 sample",
"value": "3"
}
]
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map() function.

Example in DataWeave:

```
{ 
choices:  vars.responsedata.items map {
      title: $.topic,
      value: $$
   }
}
```